# Domain name change of SQL servers involved in replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I have a situation where client wants to change their domain name of servers hosting SQL Servers(e.g. from AB to CD). I have a transactional replication with updatable subscription configured with 1 publisher, 1 distributor and 4 subscribers.

We are only changing the domain name and not hostname/IP address. Will it affect replication as it uses linked server? Linked server login used to configure during replication configuration was 'sa'. I am more concerned about replication as reconfiguration is a big headache. Also I know I'll have to change service accounts, logins, proxys etc. Any other things to take care of?

Let me know if you need any further details and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they just renaming the domain, or are they moving servers between domains? If it's the latter, are there any trusts between the old & new domains?

Comment: They want to decommission old domain and add all the replication servers in new domain.

Comment: Replication experts, can you please shed some light on it?